# How to load CSV file to display on HTML5 page and have search boxes to filter it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, web

I need a HTML5 document which reads a CSV file when page loads which will be hosted locally/on my website/our server. CSV file will have 3 lists: department, categories, product types. Page needs to have 3 search boxes for these (one for each) to search/filter for certain keyword for either department/categories/product types.

I am completely new to web dev and HTML5/jQuery, I have got the following working which you have to manually select the file and then click upload to display the contents. I was thinking of replacing the

```
reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
```

to

```
reader.readAsText(string filename);
```

reason being - I already know the filename so can specify it but I know you cannot pass a string into

```
reader.readAsText
```

Anyway my code as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSV Downloader</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv)$/;
            var localCSVfile = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Temp\Test for HTML5.csv";
            var test1 = false;
            if (regex.test(localCSVfile.toLowerCase())) {
                test1 = true;
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var table = $("<table />");
                        var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");

                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = $("<tr />");
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                            var cell = $("<td />");
                            cell.html(cells[j]);
                            row.append(cell);

                        }
                        table.append(row);
                    }

                    $("#dvCSV").html('');
                    $("#dvCSV").append(table);

                }
                reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
<hr />
Department:<br>
<input type="text" name="department">
<br>
Categories:<br>
<input type="text" name="categories">
<br>
Product Types:<br>
<input type="text" name="producttypes">
<br>
<div id="dvCSV">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want the click/upload buttons/functionality as I would like the CSV file to be loaded automatically when page loads, also the 3 search boxes should actually filter the corresponding list in the CSV file and displays it (currently search boxes do not do anything).

Answer (score 1):

Just try to change this:  `$("#upload").bind("click",function ()`  into `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: thanks, atleast this will start the CSV loading on page load however currently will not work as file load is dependent on file chosen and upload button being clicked